# How to access scrapy stats from a pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

From the scrapy [api](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/api.html) I know that a crawler contains the stats attribute, but how can I access it from a custom pipeline?

```
class MyPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        self.stats = ???
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your pipeline is an extension and you want it to access the `stats` attribute. An extension receives the Crawler object through the `from_crawler(cls, crawler)` method.

All in all, you should do something like

```
def __init__(self, stats):
    self.stats = stats

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(crawler.stats)
```

http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html#topics-stats

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you know how the from_crawler method works?

Answer (score 4):

also stats available from spider.crawler, for example (v1.1.0):

```
class ObjPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        spider.crawler.stats.inc_value('scraped_items')
        ...
```